# how change value and label of choice in collection form field type?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have collection field type like this:

```
$defaultData = array('attendances' => array('5', '4'));
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('choice', 'text')

        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('message', 'textarea')
        ->add('attendances', 'collection', array(
            'type'  => 'choice',

            'options'  => array(

                'choices'   => array('1' => 'حاضر', '0' => 'غایب'),
            ),
        ))
        ->add('send', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
```

what I get is this:

[image]

See what labels of choices are(0 and 1) and also their input name attribute, what I want is to change label and input name attr so how can i change $defaultData for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok you can do this with `data`attribute as array, you can read more about it [here](http://%60http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/field.html%60)

*Example with your code:*

```
$defaultData = array('attendances' => 
   array('key' => '5', 'key2' => '4')
);
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
    ->add('choice', 'text')
    ->add('email', 'email')
    ->add('message', 'textarea')
    ->add('attendances', 'collection', array(
            'type'  => 'choice',

            'options'  => array(

                'choices'   => array('1' => 'حاضر', '0' => 'غایب'),
            ),
            'data' => $defaultData['attendances']
        ))
    ->add('send', 'submit')
    ->getForm();
```

*result:*

```
name="form[attendances][key]"
name="form[attendances][key2]"
```

and label also `key` and `key2`

Comment: Thanks, it work fine but any idea that how can I have different label and name index for each choice item?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that if you're going to create a select, you use the `'choice'` type directly:

```
->add('attendances', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array('1' => 'حاضر', '0' => 'غایب'),))
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

You can use a predefined array to populate the choices. You can also set the default using the [data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#data) attribute.

```
$defaultData = array('attendances' => array('5' => 'One option', '4' => 'Another option'));

...
->add('attendances', 'choice', array(
                        'choices' => $defaultData["attendances"],
                        'data' => '5',))// just in case you want a preselected choice, in this case, key 5 will appear selected by default.
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have let say about 30 item of this choice type

Comment: could it be possible to generate the array beforehand and passing it to the choices field?

Comment: Do you mean $defaultData array? yes

Comment: @mohsenkw have you tried passing `$defaultdata` to `choices`?

Comment: Yes, see line two I pass it to createFormBuilder()